# Django South Seg Fault

Tags: django, segmentation-fault, django-south

I just updated from Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04, and I am having issues migrating some code that used to work.  Googling does not reveal anything that obviously looks related except some obscure R references, and though my project does use R I would not expect it to crop up in migrations.  I have never dealt with debugging seg faults before, much less in 3rd party code.  How should I proceed?

```
(project)ben@Watt:~/Projects/project/project$ python project/manage.py migrate
Error: 'rho' must be an environment not NULL: detected in C-level eval
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDIT: It looks like a problem with rpy2, found using the ltrace from the answer below.  Still wondering how that came up in migrate.

EDIT2: My R version had been updated beyond what Rpy2 likes.  Reverting fixed things.  How this came up in ./manage.py migrate is mysterious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by using `strace` since that's already installed on many systems.  That might enable you to narrow down which module is currently executing based on the system calls made.  eg

```
$ strace -o ~/tmp/strace.log -f python project/manage.py migrate
```

or, install `ltrace` and view the sequence of calls.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ltrace
$ ltrace python project/manage.py migrate
```

Failing that, since the core has been dumped, you can use gdb on the core to see exactly where the problem occurred

```
$ gdb core
```

The use commands such as `bt` to show a stack trace.  To make this easier, you may need to find executables/libraries that have debugging symbols available.

Comment: Awesome ! Dont know if this would address the problem, but learnt something new to help debug better. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

There were changes in R's C-API with R-3.0.2. Upgrade your version of rpy2.
For details, see the [issue #150 on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/issue/150/rpy2-crashes-upon-import-with-r-302).