# rpy2 robjects causing stack smashing error

Tags: python-2.7, stack-overflow, rpy2

on Ubuntu 14.04

I've suddenly started seeing the following error each time I try and import `rpy2.robjects`

```
from rpy2 import robjects
Error: 'rho' must be an environment not NULL: detected in C-level eval
*** stack smashing detected ***: python terminated
Aborted
```

I don't know any `c++` and my google research shows this is a stack overflow error. Is there some way way I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: How was rpy2 installed? Are you seeing this using the python-rpy2 package?

Comment: Hi @unutbu, yes I installed rpy2 using the python-rpy2 package.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't get the same error using python-rpy2 on Ubuntu 14.04. What happens if you `import rpy2`?

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/p/rpy/mailman/rpy-list/thread/5246F9F1.4090108@gmail.com/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19127614/190597. The error may have something to do with your version of R.

Comment: thanks @unutbu will look into it and revert.

Comment: Hi @unutbu, that worked. I had to reinstall rpy2 using `pip install rpy2 --upgrade` and then `pip install singledisptach` and now its up and running again. Thanks again for your help. Not that you need them :-) but if you post this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as answered so you can get the rep.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you solved the problem. Since you know best how the problem is solved, it would be great if you write up the solution. Then we can upvote you :)

Answer (score 4):

Following on from @unutbu's comments above and the two links posted:

http://sourceforge.net/p/rpy/mailman/rpy-list/thread/5246F9F1.4090108@gmail.com/ : "SourceForge RPy2 Error Report"

[Django South Seg Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19127614/190597)

The error seems to have been some incompatibility between the older `python-rpy2` library and a recent upgrade of `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Upgrading to `Ubuntu 14.10` *didn't* help.

However installing through `pip` (`sudo apt-get install python-pip` if you don't have it) with :

`pip install rpy2 --upgrade` and

`pip install singledispatch`  (in response to a `module missing` error)

solved the problem and rpy2 now works fine.